# datatables.net header appears on the side of the table instead of the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have created a datatables.net datatable and have all the columns and a header showing up. However, I can't get the header to be on TOP of the datatable. It goes into the side. for example,

I have this;

header [datatable]

I want this:

header

[datatable]

This is my code:

```
        var FORCE_SHOW          = false,
            TABLE_HEIGHT        = '207',
            DEFAULT_TABLE_WIDTH = 650,
            SCROLL_BAR_WIDTH    = 20;
        var logTbl  = '<table id="logTbl" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;"></table>';
        $logTab.html(logTbl);

$('#logTbl').dataTable({
            sDom: '<"header"i>t<"Footer">',
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: true,
            bPaginate: false,
            sScrollY        : TABLE_HEIGHT,
            oLanguage       : {
                sLengthMenu: "_MENU_ records per page",
                sInfo: "Logs"

            },
            bSort           : false,
            sScrollX        : '100%',
            sScrollXInner   : '800px',
            bScrollCollapse : true,
            bDestroy        : true,
            aaData : data,
            aoColumns: [
               //columns
            ]
        });
```

In a separate html i just add the table for the datatable to be put in. otherwise all html i've put in my js file here.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue? 
Thanks!

Comment: can you post the html as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped trying to use the Datatables.net way and just went straight html. It was easier to figure out. I put this in before my table:

```
<p id="LogText">Logs</p>
```

and then adjusted the way it looked in css. So I didn't have to try and change the sDom or sInfo or any of that.